# Play Console Android Vital) shows ANR at AdapterHelper.findPositionOffset (AdapterHelper.java:472)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Attaching stack trace reported by play console below.
Just to give a context this is a chatting kind of recycler-view where I add item based on socket observer and it could be 10 items per second. I have used ListAdapter with DiffUtils also but couldn’t get rid of this ANR logs.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
 at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.findPositionOffset (AdapterHelper.java:472)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.canFindInPreLayout (AdapterHelper.java:422)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.applyRemove (AdapterHelper.java:141)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterHelper.preProcess (AdapterHelper.java:102)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags (RecyclerView.java:3942)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1 (RecyclerView.java:4209)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:4010)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:4578)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1103)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:1213)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:899)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:919)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1841)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:23362)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6561)
```